# How are UQ Holder member numbers attributed?

Tags: uq-holder

In page 12 of chapter 11, Touta and Kuroumaru are officially accepted in UQ Holder. They are, respectively, attributed the numbers 7 and 11:

[image: Touta and Kuroumaru being told their numbers]

**Do these numbers mean anything in particular** and correspond to something in terms of hierarchy (of power or ranking)? If so, how powerful/ranked are Touta and Kuroumaru?
**Or are they just randomly chosen?**

Comment: I'm thinking it either has to do with power or some sort of immortality aspect

Comment: not disclosed till now. but maybe something related to negima manga. haven't read all so can't tell or sure.

Comment: It can't be based off of immortality aspect cause then miss A. K. Would be 7 too and why would the current leader have such a high number even though he is barely one step above human

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is considered canon, as I stopped reading the manga and am not sure if further details were revealed, but...

On episode 3 of the anime, when Touta and Kuromaru meet Jinbei Shishido, he tells 'em he's number 2, and Kuromaru says:

[image]

Again, not sure if this is canon. Also not sure if Kuromaru is just making an assumption, or if this is a given in the anime — there are some different things in the adaptation, and I don't remember this bit of conversation from the manga. But, if this is not an assumption, then the numbers are attributed according to how powerful the characters are.

Answer (score 0):

I think it‘s related to their potential, and not to their power, because when they are ranked, Kuroumaru is even with Touta, and Ikuu (the current number 10) is definitely stronger than Touta (at least I think so).

Comment: You said 'At least I think so'. Can you elaborate further and provide relevant sources (manga chapters, anime episodes, etc) to support your claim?